# Best way of choosing the topic which to publish data

Tags: ros, topic, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

I'm just wondering what's the best (most conventional) way of choosing on which topic to publish data. Is it better to set a default topic and remap in the launch file or for example to extract the topic name from on yaml configuration file ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146236/best-way-of-choosing-the-topic-which-to-publish-data/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most drivers and simple nodes will use a default topic name, and use remapping arguments.

Configuration of topics via the parameter server is usually only done by nodes that subscribe to a variable number of topics, such as the navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0